# Why does my monerod always consume all the RAM?

Tags: full-node, system-requirements

I have a 24/7 full-node of 10.3.1 on win7 x64

It runs with --restricted-rpc --block-sync-size 10 --rpc-bind-ip xx.xx.xx.xx --confirm-external-bind --data-dir C:\Users\user\Documents\XMRdb --add-priority-node xx.xx.xx.xx:18080  --limit-rate-up 1000

It works well at start, but the RAM consumption always gets bigger and bigger after a few hours. In the end, it eats up all my 16 GB RAM.

I tried to change block-sync-size back to 200, limit-rate-up to 50. But no help.

The status:
Height: 1351515/1351515 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 119.56 MH/s, v
5, up to date, 8(out)+35(in) connections, uptime 1d 22h 25m 24s

How can I limit the RAM consumption?

Answer (score 3):

It eats up all the RAM because it uses a very large memory mapped database (up to about 20 GB for now), and nothing else seems to need the RAM. If you really want to limit it, you could check `ulimit` (a bash internal command), which allows you to limit memory consumption:

$ ulimit -a
  [...]
  virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

eg, to limit usage to a bit less than 5 GB: `ulimit -v 5000000`

Note that if other programs need the RAM, they'll just take it, LMDB won't hold on to it (within reason). Unused RAM is not helping anyone, after al.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the strange thing is that another node I build at different place only consumes about 1 GB even after 10 days.

The status: Height: 1351758/1351758 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 114.72 MH/s, v5, up to date, 0(out)+6(in) connections, uptime 10d 4h 7m 31s

Comment: I have been running monerod with just the default options and uptime of  22 days and it just eats 131MB.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like docker stats is incorrectly reporting memory utilization. Check with  `htop`